# Spring freemarker external loader path in JavaConfig notation

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I see plenty of posts on how to set the template loader path in the application.properties file,  but I want to do it in my Java code. I have this:

```
@Autowired
FreeMarkerConfiguration freeMarkerConfiguration;

@Bean 
public FreeMarkerViewResolver freemarkerViewResolver() { 
    FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver(); 
    resolver.setCache(true); 
    resolver.setPrefix(freeMarkerConfiguration.getPrefix()); 
    resolver.setSuffix(freeMarkerConfiguration.getSuffix()); 
    return resolver; 
}

@Bean 
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() { 
    FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer(); 
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/ftl/");
    return freeMarkerConfigurer; 
}
```

So what I want is what to put in the setTemplateLoaderPath or an example of a custom FreeMarkerConfigurer.  This path will be outside the war so it needs to be like  File:/opt/share/templates/...  etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler than I could imagine.  You simply put "file:"  in front.  This worked perfectly:

```
@Bean 
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() { 
  FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer(); 
  freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("file:/opt/data/project/resources/freemarker/);
  return freeMarkerConfigurer; 
}
```

Comment:  I would suggest to externalise the file path via environment specific property file

Comment: I will.  It will be part of the FreemarkerConfiguration file,  I just wanted to show what fixed the problem.